# How to store a value from a vector and then display it on an editText in android?

Tags: android

I have a situation where there are 3 editText fields created dynamically and those values should be stored in vector and should be displayed again after i click on button "ADD" after three fields are added?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: please share your source code so far

Answer (score 0):

You should set OnClickListener

```
  final EditText editText1 = new EditText(context);
  final EditText editText2 = new EditText(context);
  final EditText editText3 = new EditText(context);

  final Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();

// Adding editTextes to layout code here....

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vector.add(editText1.getText());
                vector.add(editText2.getText());
                vector.add(editText3.getText());
            }
       });
```

Comment: Cheers. Thanks a ton, but I need to display it on those edittext fields after i click ADD button.

Comment: what's a problem? add EditTextes to List<EditText> and in for loop call list.get(i).setText(vector.get(i)) or without loop: editText1.setText(vector.get(0)); etc...